# How to handle data from json files in lean 4?

Tags: lean4

I don't know how mature or efficient Lean 4.1.0's standard feature support is.

However, I did enjoy an interesting case about benchmarking data processing languages.The challenge is to read a json file containing only strings and after processing and counting the amount of data provided, write another json file with the counted results.
https://github.com/jinyus/related_post_gen

But regardless of that, my interest is in processing basic accounting data with information from the general ledger.

```json
{
  "ledger": {
    "account_name": "Example Company",
    "account_number": "1234567890",
    "entries": [
      {
        "entry_date": "2023-10-14",
        "description": "Opening Balance",
        "debit": 10000.00,
        "credit": 0.00
      },
      {
        "entry_date": "2023-10-15",
        "description": "Sale of Products",
        "debit": 0.00,
        "credit": 5000.00
      },
      {
        "entry_date": "2023-10-16",
        "description": "Purchase of Supplies",
        "debit": 3000.00,
        "credit": 0.00
      },
      {
        "entry_date": "2023-10-17",
        "description": "Payment from Customer",
        "debit": 2000.00,
        "credit": 0.00
      },
      {
        "entry_date": "2023-10-18",
        "description": "Utilities Expense",
        "debit": 0.00,
        "credit": 1000.00
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Later, I managed to read and write files using `IO.FS.readFile`/`IO.FS.writeFile`. I also learned about the use of `Json.parse` to recognize the format, although it wouldn't know back to the string type.

#### Is it possible for lean to analyze the format (stringfy)?

I wrote this on Lean code:

```
import Lean
import Lean.Data.Json.Basic
import Lean.Data.Json.Parser
import Lean.Data.Json.Printer

open Lean Json ToJson FromJson

structure Entry : Type where
  entry_date: String
  description: String
  debit: Float
  credit: Float
deriving Lean.toJson, Lean.FromJson, Inhabited

-- Check types
-- #check #["foo"]
-- #check 1000.00

structure Ledger : Type where
  account_name: String
  account_number: String
  entries: Array Entry
deriving Lean.toJson, Lean.FromJson, Inhabited

def main : IO Unit := do
  let startTime ← IO.monoMsNow
  let s ← IO.FS.readFile "ledger_account.json"
  -- Test Json Parser
  -- let j := (Json.parse s)
  -- IO.println j

  -- TODO

  -- timestamp
  IO.println s!"Finished: {(← IO.monoMsNow) - startTime}ms\n"
```

I'm looking for some examples of data manipulation or serialization algorithms.

Comment: I’m having trouble finding your question.  Do you want to know how to take an object of type `Json` and convert it to a parsable JSON string?  Try [`Lean.Json.render`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Data/Json/Printer.html#Lean.Json.render) and/or [`Lean.Json.pretty`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Data/Json/Printer.html#Lean.Json.pretty).  Admittedly the API and documentation leave a lot to be desired at the moment.  (I wonder if `Json` is going to be moved into `Std` where it would get more user-facing support.)

Comment: Oh wait.  It looks like printing a Json object already should use Json.pretty.  So I am again not sure what you question is?

Comment: Hi @JasonRute, I apologize for not clarifying or highlighting enough. But the idea is what you mentioned. Although I would like to treat the file data individually (by structure fields).

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want.  I use the derive handlers for `ToJson` and `FromJson` to connect your classes to the `Json` type and round trip the Json from your file.  Note the need to go from the `Except` monad to the `IO` monad.  (Sorry, about an earlier version of this answer which got confused about the ToJson handler.)

```
import Lean
import Lean.Data.Json.Basic
import Lean.Data.Json.Parser
import Lean.Data.Json.Printer

open Lean Json ToJson FromJson

structure Entry: Type where
  entry_date: String
  description: String
  --debit: Float
  --credit: Float
deriving ToJson, FromJson, Inhabited, Repr

-- Check types
-- #check #["foo"]
-- #check 1000.00

structure Ledger : Type where
  account_name: String
  account_number: String
  entries: Array Entry
deriving Lean.ToJson, Lean.FromJson, Inhabited, Repr

def get_ledger_from_json_string (s: String): Except String Ledger := do
  let j : Json <- Json.parse s
  let ledger : Ledger <- fromJson? j
  return ledger
  
def ledger_account_string := "{     \"account_name\": \"Example Company\",     \"account_number\": \"1234567890\",     \"entries\": [       {         \"entry_date\": \"2023-10-14\",         \"description\": \"Opening Balance\",         \"debit\": 10000.00,         \"credit\": 0.00       },       {         \"entry_date\": \"2023-10-15\",         \"description\": \"Sale of Products\",         \"debit\": 0.00,         \"credit\": 5000.00       },       {         \"entry_date\": \"2023-10-16\",         \"description\": \"Purchase of Supplies\",         \"debit\": 3000.00,         \"credit\": 0.00       },       {         \"entry_date\": \"2023-10-17\",         \"description\": \"Payment from Customer\",         \"debit\": 2000.00,         \"credit\": 0.00       },       {         \"entry_date\": \"2023-10-18\",         \"description\": \"Utilities Expense\",         \"debit\": 0.00,         \"credit\": 1000.00       }     ]   }"
#eval (get_ledger_from_json_string ledger_account_string)
#eval toJson (get_ledger_from_json_string ledger_account_string).toOption.get!

def main : IO Unit := do
  let startTime ← IO.monoMsNow
  let s ← IO.FS.readFile "ledger_account.json"
  -- Test Json Parser
  let ledger : Ledger <- IO.ofExcept (get_ledger_from_json_string s)
  IO.println (toJson ledger)

  -- timestamp
  IO.println s!"Finished: {(← IO.monoMsNow) - startTime}ms\n"
```

Edit: Also notice the format in your file is a bit off from what the program expects.  Do one of the following:

1. delete the outer object with the field "ledger" in your file (like in the inline example I provided in the code),
2. Make another structure `LedgerFile` which just has a field `ledger` and add ToJson and FromJson handlers, or
3. Before using the `fromJson` for `Ledger`, extract the "ledger" field from the `Json` object `j`.  I think you can do this with [`Json.getObj?`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Data/Json/Basic.html#Lean.Json.getObj?).

Comment: Lean has Json parsers in its stdlib? :o

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Yes, a lot of Lean is built in Lean and the language server uses JSON.  That is at least one reason it exists, besides being an overall standard communication format.

Comment: There are also more general parsing libraries available: https://github.com/lurk-lab/Megaparsec.lean and https://github.com/fgdorais/lean4-parser These are important since Lean core is unlikely to accept new parsing features unless they impact Lean core itself.