# How to find the data type of a Json value that in lean4, to perform type validation. (Functional programming in lean)

Tags: lean4, programming-languages

Basically I am taking in a json object in lean4 as input and I want to check whether a particular feild like 'age' should always be Nat not something else depending on the schema that the user has provided.

(The schema is not constant so I can't hardcode it. Like answered in one of the previous questions.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/how-to-handle-data-from-json-files-in-lean-4

Comment: I’m find trouble making time to answer this, but the solution is pretty simple.  You first convert your string into Lean’s Json type.  (See above question and the answer.) From there you can check whatever conditions you need.  You can either leave it in Json or convert it to your own datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Lean's built-in JSON functionality allows you to do two main things:

- Convert a JSON string into the type `Json`.  Once in this type, you can do any sort of checks and manipulation.
- Label your custom Types with `ToJson` and `FromJson` type classes.  These let you respectively convert your type to  `Json` and back.  This can be done automatically in some cases with `deriving ToJson, FromJson`, but I think in your case, you would have to add them manually.

Note: It would be cool if there was an automatic way to turn a JSON schema into a Lean inductive or structure with the associated `ToJson` and `FromJson` type classes.  There is no reason this couldn't be done, but I don't think anyone has got to it.

All my examples will use the following import and open namespaces:

```
import Lean

open Lean Json ToJson FromJson
```

Here is an example where I take in a JSON object (dictionary) and check if the "success" field is true.  If so, I return the "message" field, otherwise I return the "error" field.  Lean's `Except String` monad does all the error handling if the JSON isn't in the correct format.  (If Lean's monads are new to you, I might recommend you skim [Functional Programming in Lean](https://lean-lang.org/functional_programming_in_lean/).)  I wrote the code more verbose at the start of the function and used more and more notational tricks to shorten the code near the end.

```
def process_json_response (s : String) : Except String String := do
  let j : Json <- Json.parse s
  -- use Json.getObjVal? and Json.getBool? to read Json
  -- if assumptions fail, then an error is returned
  let successJson : Json <- j.getObjVal? "success"
  let isSuccess : Bool <- successJson.getBool?
  if isSuccess then
    -- return "message" field
    -- Using Json.getObjValAs? to automatically convert the result to a String
    let message : String <- j.getObjValAs? String "message"
    return "Message: " ++ message
  else
    -- return "error" field otherwise
    -- using `(<- ...)` notation to make more compact
    return "Error: " ++ (<- j.getObjValAs? String "error")
```

We can test how this function behaves as follows:

```
#eval process_json_response "{\"success\":true, \"message\":\"Hello world!\"}"
/-
Except.ok "Message: Hello world!"
-/
#eval process_json_response "{\"success\": false, \"error\": \"All your base are belong to us!\"}"
/-
Except.ok "Error: All your base are belong to us!"
-/
#eval process_json_response "0"
/-
Except.error "object expected"
-/
#eval process_json_response "{\"message\": \"Hello World!\"}"
/-
Except.error "property not found: success"
-/
#eval process_json_response "{\"success\": null}"
/-
Except.error "Bool expected"
-/
#eval process_json_response "{\"success\": true, \"error\": \"All your base are belong to us!\"}"
/-
Except.error "String expected"
-/
```

Finally, we can make a custom type in which we intend to store the JSON data.  We will even make it more complicated by having either the JSON data be an object as above or a non-negative integer (maybe some sort of error code).  We will also implement the `ToJson` and `FromJson` type classes.

```
inductive ServerResponse
| success (message: String)  -- {"success": true, "message": <message>}
| fail (error: String)       -- {"success": false, "error": <error>}
| code (n : Nat)             -- <n>

instance : ToJson ServerResponse where
  toJson : ServerResponse -> Json
  | .success msg => Json.mkObj [("success", Json.bool True), ("message", Json.str msg)]
  | .fail err => Json.mkObj [("success", Json.bool False), ("error", Json.str err)]
  | .code n => Json.num n

instance : FromJson ServerResponse where
  fromJson? (j : Json) : Except String ServerResponse := do
    -- using pattern matching here to cover different cases
    match j.getInt? with -- is it an integer?
    | .ok n =>  -- integer
      match n.toNat' with  -- is it non-negative?
      | some n =>  -- non-negative integer
        return ServerResponse.code n
      | none =>  -- negative integer
        -- return an error message
        Except.error "Got negative number!  Can't convert to ServerResponse."
    | .error _ =>  -- not an integer
      if (<- j.getObjValAs? Bool "success") then
        return ServerResponse.success (<- j.getObjValAs? String "message")
      else
        return ServerResponse.fail (<- j.getObjValAs? String "message")
```

We can reimplement `process_json_response` as above.  It is a bit cleaner, since we can work with our custom type.

```
def process_json_response2 (s : String) : Except String String := do
  let j : Json <- Json.parse s
  let response : ServerResponse <- fromJson? j
  match response with
  | .success msg =>
    return s!"Message: {msg}"
  | .fail err =>
    return s!"Error: {err}"
  | .code n =>
    return s!"Code: {n}"
```